# Signed cookies from Rails app to Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, sinatra

I have two applications, one is a Sinatra app and another is a Rails app. I have set signed cookies in the Rails app and I need to send that cookie from the browser to Sinatra.

The question is how can I see the contents of that cookie from my Sinatra app if the cookie is signed?

The apps are under the same domain with different subdomains. Is this possible or even secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed share cookies amongst sub domains. You need to set the cookie domain to `.your-domain.com`  Note the leading dot, it is important.

To read the cookies, the 2 sites will have to share the cookie signing secret.

In Sinatra you can set it in Rack: [from Sinatra FAQ](http://sinatrarb.com/faq.html)

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                       :domain => 'foo.com',
                       :path => '/',
                       :expire_after => 2592000, # In seconds
                       :secret => 'change_me'
```

So you would need to set secret the same as `Rails.application.config.cookie_secret` in your Rails config

Comment: what is the path? Also, in development I need to have the domain to localhost how would I set the domain there? The issue is that the cookie is signed so when I get the request on sinatra app and I look at the request.cookie["somecookie"] I get the signed value from rails not the actual value I need